# How can I have a dynamic/virtual attribute AND have as an attribute of the Model?

Tags: plugin-development, models, attribute

Take the [example](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods) of a model with a `firstName` and `lastName`.

I know I can add a `getFullName` method to the model, and `$model->fullName` will run through the getter.

However, I'd like the attribute to also remain part of the model (accessible through $model->attributes), which if I use the getter, it isn't.

If I use the getter AND include the same name in `defineAttributes`, the getter is ignored.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're out of luck.  You can't go through the magic `__get()` logic and have a concrete `get` method and use both.  How will Yii/PHP know which one you're referring to when you do `$model->fullName`?

Comment: Ok, I thought that might be the case.

Comment: I don't necessarily need it in both places, I just need a way to get the populated model, including `fullName`, without having to manually add it every time.

Comment: Not sure I'm following that 100%. Maybe a case for a behavior ? (http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/44/behaviors-events/)

Comment: A behavior in Yii is similar to a Ruby mixin or PHP trait if you're familiar with those.

Comment: I'll look at behaviors, thanks. Here's the real example of what I'm trying to do: https://gist.github.com/timkelty/09b42e50105b6c420c5b

Comment: Ah duh...is it just a matter of overriding the populateModel method in my model? Does that also get called with `new MyModel()`, or should I override the constructor?

Comment: You'll probably want to override the constructor.  Just be sure and call `parent::__construct()`, too.